# Iterative or Lazy Reservoir Sampling

Tags: sampling, algorithms

I'm fairly well acquainted with using [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to sample from a set of undetermined length in a single pass over the data. One limitation of this approach, in my mind, is that it still requires a pass over the entire data set before any results can be returned. Conceptually this makes sense, since one has to allow items in the entirety of the sequence the opportunity to replace previously encountered items to achieve a uniform sample.

Is there a way to be able to yield some random results **before** the entire sequence has been evaluated? I'm thinking of the kind of lazy approach that would fit well with python's great [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library. Perhaps this could be done within some given error tolerance? I'd appreciate any sort of feedback on this idea!

Comment: The strict answer to your question is "no" for the simple reason that the distribution of elements of sequence could change after a certain point and if you only observe the first $n$, then you will miss the change in distribution. Now, if you specify what you mean by error tolerance, then there is room for maneuver.